# Using .map without creating a new array

Tags: arrays, angular, array.prototype.map

Let's say that i have this data:

```
const celsius = [-15, -5, 0, 10, 16, 20, 24, 32]
const fahrenheit = celsius.map(t => t * 1.8 + 32);
```

So `celsius` is a array, and `fahrenheit` is using `map`, that is using `celsius`to create another array with the following values:

```
>[0]
    >5
    >23
    >32
    >50
    >60.8
    >68
    >75.2
    >89.6
```

My problem is the new array it creates, because i need only the values of the array, and the array [0] is makes the work with it very difficult. So my question is: Can I create a array with `.map` without creating the array[0]?

Comment: I think you're confused. fahrentheit only contains numbers: 5, 23, etc. The same number of elements as the celsius array.

Comment: It is unclear what are you asking. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MDN -

[The **map**() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

I don't know how you got that output but map always creates a new **array**

So to answer you no.

Comment: Thanks, i'm going to find another solution